# C# - Split at 20 characters but not if it is in between a word

Tags: c#, string, split

I want to split a string into smaller parts, not exceeding a string length of 20 characters.

The current code is able to split an input string into an array of strings of length 20. However, this could cut a word.

The current code is:

```
string[] Array;

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
{
  if (i % 20 == 0 && i != 0) {
    sb.Append('~');
  }
  sb.Append(input[i]);
}

Array =  sb.ToString().Split('~');
```

For an input of this: `Hello. This is a string. Goodbye.`, the output would be `['Hello. This is a str', 'ing. Goodbye.']`.

However, I don’t want the string to be cut if it’s a word. That word should move to the next string in the array. How can I get the following output instead?

`['Hello. This is a', 'string. Goodbye.']`

Comment: _I don’t want the string to be cut if it’s a word_ please explain, even the letter "a" can be a word

Comment: What if you have a word longer than 20 characters?

Comment: Yes, I meant if the surrounding is not a space when cut, I guess. "a" on it's own is fine as it doesn't change meaning. However, 'str''ing' may not necessarily make sense.

Comment: Split on spaces, then concat until size of string + size of next word is more than 20

Comment: If longer than than 20 characters, would just split at that point. I guess in this case, I would need to consider a word at a time?

Comment: Rafalon, that's a brilliant idea. I'll try this approach.

Comment: What is `input` exactly? Could you use .LastIndexOf to find the space on or before char 20 and split there?

Comment: `input` is a string. So something like 'Hello. This is a string. Goodbye.' as in the example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could be more elegant but this will split the string to lines of a maximum number of characters. The words will be kept together unless they exceed the given length.

```
    public static string[] SplitString(string input, int lineLen)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        string[] words = input.Split(' ');
        string line = string.Empty;
        string sp = string.Empty;
        foreach (string w in words)
        {
            string word = w;
            while (word != string.Empty)
            {
                if (line == string.Empty)
                {
                    while (word.Length >= lineLen)
                    {
                        sb.Append(word.Substring(0, lineLen) + "~");
                        word = word.Substring(lineLen);
                    }
                    if (word != string.Empty)
                        line = word;
                    word = string.Empty;
                    sp = " ";
                }
                else if (line.Length + word.Length <= lineLen)
                {
                    line += sp + word;
                    sp = " ";
                    word = string.Empty;
                }
                else
                {
                    sb.Append(line + "~");
                    line = string.Empty;
                    sp = string.Empty;
                }
            }
        }
        if (line != string.Empty)
            sb.Append(line);
        return sb.ToString().Split('~');
    }
```

To test:

```
string[] lines = SplitString("This is a test of the string splitter KGKGKJGKGHKJHJKJKHGJHGhghsjagsjasgajsgjahs yes!", 20);
foreach (string line in lines)
{
    Console.WriteLine(line);
}
```

Output:

```
This is a test of the
string splitter
KGKGKJGKGHKJHJKJKHGJ
HGhghsjagsjasgajsgja
hs yes!
```

Comment: I like this because it is reusable (variable string length) and accounts for words over the specified length

Comment: This seems to be off by one. "This is a test of the" is 21 characters including spaces.  I think it needs to be: else if (line.Length + sp + word.Length <= lineLen)

Answer (score 3):

First split your sentence on word-boundary:

```
var words = myString.Split();
```

Now concatenate words as long as not more than 20 characters are within your current line:

```
var lines = new List<string> { words[0] };
var lineNum = 0;
for(int i = 1; i < words.Length; i++)
{
    if(lines[lineNum].Length + words[i].Length + 1 <= 20)
        lines[lineNum] += " " + words[i];
    else
    {
        lines.Add(words[i]);
        lineNum++;
    }
}
```

Here is a fiddle for testing: https://dotnetfiddle.net/s0LrFC

Comment: Sorry for my comment deletion, I was unsure about the `.Split()` (as I used `.Split(' ')`) and thought maybe it was because of this

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's faster to split it only at places where it needs to be, instead of every word. With `lines.SelectMany(x => Split(x, 80)` can be used with multiline texts:

```cs
private static IEnumerable<string> Split(string text, int maxLength)
{
    var i = 0;
    while (i + maxLength < text.Length)
    {
        var partIndex = text.LastIndexOf(' ', i + maxLength, maxLength);
        if (partIndex == -1)
            partIndex = i + maxLength;
        yield return text[i..partIndex];
        i = partIndex + 1;
    }

    yield return text[i..];
}
```